# Linux - SSH Non-Root User Connection Closed /bin/false

Tags: ssh

I am trying to debug why my non-root user is failing to keep an ssh connection open despite a successful login. One I am notified that the ssh connection was successful it closes immediately. the user is `ghost` and I have followed other investigative tips such as `cat /etc/passwd | grep ghost`, which returns `ghost:x:187:117:,,,:/home/ghost:/bin/false` and an understanding that `/bin/false` could be causing the failure, but I'm not sure the best solution and what else I should check for. It has been a while since I first set up this user and would rather debug the scenario than remove and create again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shell for the user ghost is set to [`/bin/false`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/false). When ghost logs in, /bin/false is executed, it runs and then exits.  it is the login shell, when it exits ghost gets disconnected.

To solve the problem you will need to provide ghost with a suitable shell e.g. `/bin/bash` or similar.

Are you sure that you need to log in as this user ? It feels like it is a service account that correctly has /bin/false set as it's shell to stop anyone from logging in.